# Hm-10 Bluetooth Module enter in undiscoverable state after 5 seconds of turning it on

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, hm-10

When I turn on Hm-10 Bluetooth module, it's LED blinks for 5 seconds and then it become still ( the led is always on without blinking ).

At these 5 seconds I can find it when I make a search for nearby Bluetooth devices and I can enter to AT command ( I write AT and it returns OK), after the 5 seconds   can't find it with search and when I use AT commands it does not respond.

Can you help me to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same problem with Hm-10 and when I bring another one it works perfect.
The problem may be hardware problem and you must replace it or a problem with the firmware (I uploaded another firmware and the problem wasn't solved but may be another firmware will solve the problem)